# Change the path of WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, iis

We´re are using Akamai here and I would like to know if there´s any way to change the path of WebResource.axd so we can cache the file in Akamai´s network.

The ASP page automatically inserts the  WebResource.axd?d=9MSi9kc8rKZ-yU_r-9KIXg2&t=633595228754539605 in our pages. I would like the change the url to another one.

The WebResource.axd is loading the javascript file WebUIValidation.js

Or ... maybe suppress the webresource.axd somehow and load the file manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to stop ASP.NET from rendering WebResource.axd. A possible workaround is to override the rendering of your page and replace every occurrence of WebResource.axd with the cached file url.

Answer (score -1):

Would this help?

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);       
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("WebResource", "WebResource.axd", "~/WebResource.axd");
    routes.MapPageRoute("ScriptResource", "ScriptResource.axd", "~/ScriptResource.axd");
}
```